# Storing and retrieving array list values in shared preferences android returns null

Tags: android, firebase, arraylist, set, sharedpreferences

I am trying to store and retrieve values in shared preferences but first time when I open the app, the shared preference value is NULL. From next time, it shows the values of previous key.

This is my code,

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
Set<String> set;
sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(mypreference, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
   databaseReferenceImages.child(postkey).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            Set<String> sharedlist = new HashSet<String>();
            sharedlist.addAll(second);
            editor.putStringSet("notifications", sharedlist);
            editor.apply();
            for (String a : sharedlist) {
                Log.d("thesharedlist", a);
            }
}

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

set = sharedPreferences.getStringSet("notifications", null);
    if (set != null) {
        for (String a : set) {
            Log.d("thesetis", a);
        }
    }
```

Here I want the values for a particular "POSTKEY"(Poskey will be different for each post)
I want to get the value of array list or "SET" outside of onDataChange method so I used shared Preferences. Its working fine for a String but not for Array list or Set. The following problem occurs,

- When I open the app for the first time and click a particular post,
  the value of the shared preference value which is returned is NULL.
- When I open the same post for the second time, the values are
  returning perfectly.
- When I open second post ,the values of
  previous post are returning.
- When I open the first post again, the values of second post are returning.

I don't know where I am wrong. I tried clearing the values of shared preferences each time the app opens but the same problem occurs. I even followed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057845/save-arraylist-to-sharedpreferences) but nothing worked. Any help would be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: try `editor.commit`

Comment: It's not working @LunarWatcher

Comment: have you checked to see that the data is actually saved into the editor? That the relevant code actually is called

Comment: you can't save an array into `sharedpreference` and the first time which you  didn't have anything in it, it should return null, what else do you expect?

Comment: Could you tell me how to check that? @LunarWatcher

Comment: You have this logtag in your code: ` Log.d("thesharedlist", a);` have you checked logcat to see that there actually is output with that tag and data? If it doesn't show up, the code isn't called

Comment: I am storing a set into sharedpreference and could you explain me what do you mean by "it doesn't have anything for the first time"? @MehranZamani

Comment: Yes, the values are printing @LunarWatcher

Comment: it means when your application run for first time, nothing is stored in `sharedpreference`.

Comment: Values will get stored in sharedpreference when the post is clicked. So, what should I  do now @MehranZamani

Comment: But its working fine in case of String. I used similar concept. @MehranZamani

Comment: putStringSet(String key, Set<String> values)
Set a set of String values in the preferences editor, to be written back once commit() or apply() is called.

Comment: Can you explain me in code? I still don't get the clear idea @MehranZamani

Comment: FYI  In this line, sharedlist.addAll(second), I am copying the values of arraylist named "second" to the Set. @MehranZamani

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to get null first time, you can do one of these 2 things:

1- call `getStringSet` differently

```
sharedPreferences.getStringSet("notifications", "it isn't saved yet!");
```

2- save default value to `sharedpreference` before `getStringSet`

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
editor.putStringSet("notifications", sharedlist);
editor.apply();
```

If you want to get current post not previous one, you should save it before. my guess is that you click on post number one and it's stored in `sharedpreference` and when you want to check the second one, it returns first one.

Comment: I have already done the second thing. Kindly Look at the code I have posted in question.

Comment: dear @Anusha, i did read your code. you didn't do seconde solution. `addValueEventListener` is an asynchronous, which might run after `getStringSet`.

Comment: Thanks !! So where should I write the code of getStringSet?

Comment: inside of `addValueEventListener` **or** put your `putStringSet` outside of `addValueEventListener`  and then call `getStringSet`.

Comment: I want to get the values out of addValueEventListener so I am putting inside the Set and retrieving and I am using getStringSet outside of addValueEventListener only

Comment: could you tell me why outside?

Comment: The values which are returned in addValueEventListener wont be available outside. Since  I want those values, I am using shared preference for it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144166/discussion-between-mehran-zamani-and-anusha).

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue by storing it in sharedpreference after 1500ms.

This is my code,

```
   final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
        set = sharedPreferences.getStringSet("notifications", null);
            if (set != null) {
                for (String a : set) {
                    Log.d("thesetis", a);
                }
            }
        }
    }, 1500);
```